# Proof of Scheffe lemma : question on the proof.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Scheffé lemma says : $f_n\to f$ a.e. and $\int f_n\to \int f$ (and $f_n,f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$) then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb R^d)$

In [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_de_Scheff%C3%A9) they do as follow :
$$\int (f_n-f)^++\int (f_n-f)^-=\int|f_n-f|\tag{1}$$
$$\int (f_n-f)^+-\int(f_n-f)^-=\int(f_n-f)\tag{2}.$$

Since $0\leq (f_n-f)^+\leq f$ and $(f_n-f)^+\to 0$, we have by DCT,$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int(f_n-f)^+=0.$$
Using $(2)$ and $\int f_n\to \int f$, we get $$\int (f_n-f)^-\to 0,$$ therefore, using $(1)$, the claim follow.

---

**Question**

Why do we need $(2)$ ? (of course it's not important, but we can make the argument easier). Don't we have $0\leq (f_n-f)^\pm\leq f$, and thus, by DCT $$\int (f_n-f)^\pm\to 0,$$ and thus, using $(1)$ the claim follow. This is not correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f-f_n)^{+}$ is either $0$ or $f-f_n$ so $(f-f_n)^{+} \leq f$. This allows us to use DCT. It is not true that $0 \leq (f_n-f)^{\pm} \leq f$. In fact the proof above is also wrong. DCT applies to $\int(f-f_n)^{+}$ but  not to $\int (f_n-f)^{+}$. Once you see that $\int(f-f_n)^{+} \to 0$ you can use the facts that $\int(f-f_n)^{-}=\int(f-f_n)^{+}-\int (f-f_n) $ and  $|f-f_n|=(f-f_n)^{+}+(f-f_n)^{-}$.

Comment: Ok, it's my false, I thought that $(f_n-f)^+$ and $(f-f_n)^+$ where the same. Indeed, it's not. But what is true is that $0\leq (f_n-f)^-\leq f$... but I understand now. Thank you :)